# How to set auto width for different screen sizes?

Tags: css, width

My website uses this code for `width` and it is shown perfectly on a 15.6 inch screen, but for mobile screens and netbook & tablet screens of 10 inch, the website is completely messed up. It uses a fixed width, I tried to make it `auto`, `100px` but no success. here is the css code:

```
#container {
    width: 1180px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Website is [HERE](http://www.elemonya.com)
there is a background image and container is placed over it. How to modify this code to have auto width for different screens?

PS: Script is opencart.

Comment: [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) or use percentage.

Comment: you might use `width: 90%` instead of `px` but your site might still look messed up because the inner elements/containers might be using fixed width. So to actually make your site work on small screens, you've to eliminate fixed width/height, and adapt your website to display appropriately on different screen sizes using media queries, as @Ruddy has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a percent rather than a fixed width in your CSS.

```
#container 
{
width: 95%; 
margin: 5px auto;
text-align: left;
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

If you want to use different CSS depending on the device it is being viewed on, your best bet is to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) as suggested by @Ruddy

Comment: thank you ffor answers. but, I forgot to mentionn this, THERE IS A BACKGROUND IMAGE. I tried those but then the container covers the whole image. I want to modify this as the image will not be modified. here is how it should be : [link](http://www.elemonya.com/question.png)

Comment: `code  
body {  
background: #3B3A42 url("../image/pattern15.png");  
color: #000000;  
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;  
margin: 0px;  
padding: 0px;  
}  
  
/* layout */  
.wrapper{  
padding: 0 20px;  
}  
#container {  
width: 1180px;  
margin: 50px auto;  
text-align: left;  
background-color:#FFF;  
}  `

Comment: Worked for me with '%'

Answer (score 0):

Try this below css.. ( for all width apply in max-with:100% )

```
#container {
width: 1180px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 5px auto;
text-align: left;
background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**->** Try using a percent or min-width and max-width rather than a fixed width in your CSS.

**------percent -------**

```
 #container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

**min-width and max-width**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1180px;
  min-width: 380px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Try using these two methods. And if these don't work then use media query.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).